# Lost my question due to logging in at 'incorrect' time

Tags: discussion, bug

I guess it's somewhat ironic to write this question on a site about UX, but, I've come to this site (never used it before) and wrote my question. When I tried to submit I was informed I needed to sign in or log in. I'm a long user of the SE sites so I clicked on the log on option, logged in with my SE account, and have lost my question.

Now, I know the voting system, you write a 'bad' question, you get down-voted and probably not very good answers (understandably). So, naturally I spent a while writing my question, with screen shots, to ensure clarity. As I've said, at this point, if I try to log in, I can't do anything to save my post (and posting as anonymous is just unclear and unintuitive to what it does so I left it).

I assume this is probably true of all the SE sites but regardless, is this something which can be fixed? If one have to be logged in first then why give me an option to write the question first?

Comment: It does appear this has happened before as there are a couple of posts on MetaStackOverflow about this same situation - [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119118/writing-a-long-post-losing-everything) and also [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34110/it-should-be-possible-to-log-in-in-the-middle-of-writing-a-question-without-los). However doesn't look like there was any answer as to the cause. If I can find out what happened then I'll post an answer to let you know.

Comment: Thank you @JonW